# Accessing table with only foreign Keys in Entity Data Framework

Tags: entity-framework

i am new to Entity Data framework
i have tables

```
Actions ( Actionid (pk) ,Actionname , ... )
Roles ( Roleid(pk) , Rolename , .... ) 
ActionRoles( Actionid(pk,fk)  , Roleid(fk) ) [Mapping Table]
```

Please Suggest me the LINQ to get the `RoleNames` for Perticular `ActionID` 
(Note : there is No class created with Name `ActionRoles` in entitydesigner.cs as because it doesn't have any other column name then `ActionId` and `RoleID` )

Thank you in Advance

Comment: In your `ActionRoles` both FK must be part of PK or your Action will have only single role.

Comment: @Ladislav in ActionRoles ActionID is only PK , for single action there are more than one role

Comment: If `ActionID` is only PK then action cannot have more then one role because once you insert another record with the same `ActionID` into `ActionRoles` you will get an exception.

Comment: @Ladislav Fine u r right ,but my problem is how to access ActionRoles

Answer (score 1):

When you have a link table like this, adding all tables to the Entity Model should create 2 way relationship Properties between the 2 end tables, hiding the link table completely allowing you to access via something like:

```
IEnumerable<string> roleNames = Entities.Actions
    .First(a => a.Actionid == actionid)
    .Roles
    .Select(r => r.Rolename);
```

where `actionid` is an `int variable` containing the `actionid` you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

For a discussion of how to handle many-to-many relationships such as this (both foreign keys must be in the ActionRoles primary key as indicated in the comment to your question), see these tutorials:
For EF 4.0: http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-–-getting-started-part-5
For Ef 4.1: http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Thank you for the Provided link.